# Confusion with Foreign key and manyToManyField in Django

Tags: django

I was creating library system with Django and also I was designing database. So, I have this logic that one student can have many books but one can belong to one student. Thus, student table needs to have foreign key of book table. But, it restricts us to choose ONLY ONE book Right? But I want to allow for student to choose many books thus I need to use ManyToManyField(). But, if I use that my one-to-many logic turns into many-to-many. Is what I am doing correct? Again, logically, one-to-many relationship is correct BUT it restricts us to choose ONLY one book. To solve this problem, we can use ManyToManyField() but the logic turns into many-to-many which will mean student can have many books but one book can belong to many student which is wrong since book can belong to one student.

Comment: Do you want  your student to have multiple books and one book should belong to only one user.

Comment: @SachinWhitemanD, yeah, I mean, if one student takes one or several books then those chosen books should not be available to other students until that books are returned

Comment: @SachinWhitemanD, so, is it basically ok to use manyToManyField to allow student choose more than one book and somehow write logic disabling those chosen books until they are returned?

Comment: use a foreign key field in books model

Comment: @SachinWhitemanD, you mean I can use manyToManyField in student model and foreign key in books model. Right?

Comment: follow my answer, manyToMany Field is not needed at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a foreign key in the Books model.

```
from django.db import models
class Student(models.Model):
    pass
    # student fields goes here

class Book(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    # other Book fields goes here
```

so that everytime , a student borrows a book, the book will be updated with a student. and when book is returned it can be set null.

So That a student can have multiples books at a time, but book will have only one student at a time.